# Why the behavior is not consistent for the two double values in case of arithmetic operation

Tags: java

Below is my code snippet, the issue that I am facing is in arithmetic operation with double.

when `double value = 1489.260;` then after dividing by 100 I get output `14.89260` (which is correct)

**Problem :** But in case `double value =148.9260;` then after dividing by 100 I get output `1.4892599999999998` (*which is rounded off value*).

- **Question 1:** Why behavior is different in two cases ?
- **Question 2:** How can I get output without rounding off the value ? **i.e 1.48960.**

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int unitOfQuotation = 100;

    double value =148.9260;//1489.260(works fine);//14.89260(works fine);

    Double bidValue = new Double(value/unitOfQuotation);

    Double bidValue1 = Double.valueOf(value/unitOfQuotation);

    System.out.println(bidValue);
    System.out.println(bidValue1);

/*      
 *  Output in case of value =148.9260;
 *      1.4892599999999998
    1.4892599999999998*/

/*      
*  Output in case of value =1489.260;
*           14.8926
    14.8926*/

}
```

Comment: Use BigDecimal not Double. Btw be consistent with variables is better to divide by same type of veriables (double/double)

Comment: Double is always rounded, if you want to correctly represent values with arbitrary digits use BigDecimal for example.

Comment: @Smutje : When I use BigDecimal finalBid = BigDecimal.valueOf(value/unitOfQuotation)  then also the result is 1.4892599999999998.  Also I am now doing double/double. But same result.

Comment: Yes, because the result of `value/unitOfQuotation)` is a double before it gets converted to a `BigDecimal`. Try working with `BigDecimal` from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options on handling the rounding errors:

1. Don't bother. These errors are so small, that most of the time they are negligible. (This is not valid for finance and maybe scientific calculations)
2. Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). But be aware that this may slow down your program and therefore isn't suitable for games.

On top of that you should learn [how floating points are implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and [what you should keep in mind while using them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Furthermore, here is how you can print the floating points:

```
double number = 148.9260 / 100;
System.out.printf("my number is: %.4f%n", number);
```

Where `%f` stands for floating point, and `%n` for newline. The `.4` tells the formatter to use 4 digits after the decimal point. See [the formatter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail) for further information.

If you only want a String, you can use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String myNumberString = String.format("%.4f", number); // no %n!
```

Comment: Could you please also suggest a solution if I do not need to print this value but rather need to store it in DB or return it from an method

Comment: @Harshit This is the `don't care`-case. You should only round the values for displaying purposes. If you really want a clean float in DB or returning from a method, use BigDecimal (or something similar)

Answer (score 2):

Floating points calculation are not exact, since these values can't be exactly represented in memory bits. Most of the time, they are approximately represented, hence having some deviation in calculation.

For more details, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal for floating point calculations. Results are never exact. However, there are standard work-arounds:

- Whenever you print a variable, set the precision to something sensible. This will ensure rounding takes place in the background and you will see a predictable result.
- When comparing floating point amounts, allow for a small discrepancy. e.g. if (abs(v2 -v1) < 0.000001) ...

Comment: You will need an `Math.abs` in case v1 is greater than v2: `if (Math.abs(v2 - v1) > 0.000001) { /* not equal */`. (I assumed you want to check for inequality, since epsilon does not make sense while only comparing)

Comment: Thanks absurb-mind. I forgot the abs() test - have edited the reply.